# Camera Interfaces can be used with Raspberry pi

Tags: camera

Could one interface any CMOS camera on the raspberry pi? I'm studying CMOS camera sensor using Raspberry Pi and Picamera. So far I found it very useful to control a camera manually using python. But I wonder if I can test more board camera modules using the raspberry pi. For example. there are more than 20 camera modules in the Omnivision that provides CMOS sensor for picamera. Since the company provides various CMOS camera, I want to try interfacing them on the raspberry pi. Would it be possible? And then what kind of ports (I2C, SPI, SDA etc) are required?

Comment: Some possible information and further links in [this question and answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22963/using-other-camera-modules-to-build-custom-webcams/22971#22971)

Answer (score 1):

All known instances of other cameras working with the rpi should be listed on the [wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals). Start with a USB version with linux support ([first google hit](http://www.e-consystems.com/M12-CMOS-USB-3-Camera.asp)). You will likely get better results with the pi camera as most other cameras use slower ports.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, in theory. Practically, you will probably need a breakout board or an adapter of some kind to match the connector and interface of the camera module. You will also need to find out how that particular module (or family) is interfaced with. If a datasheet can be found, that should contain useful information for both projects.

For starting points, you might try looking for (microcontroller) projects using the same kind of camera module and if there are any kernel drivers for the module on other systems.

In any case, it will most likely be a great deal of work with somewhat special skills and usually very weak and hard to attain information and political issues. In other words, a magnificient learning experience. I urge you to publicly document all efforts. :)